# Generate/extract shape from existing mesh

Tags: three.js

Is it somehow possible to extract shape from mesh object ? I have THREE.mesh object created from vectors and i want to convert/duplicate one side of that object into shape and apply some extrude woodo on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, a shape is made from points, too, so where is the problem? You could get the vertices from checking the face normal, so you know which side the faces are showing and then you take their vertices if they face your specific side and "copy" them into a shape? 
Although i guess this is not so easy because you would need only those vertices that form the outline of the convex hull of those faces... just an idea, though